# Problem with beamer columns

Tags: beamer, pdftex, columns

I have just recompiled with pdflatex a presentation and the text in the first column of one of the slides does not appear in the pdf. The source code is exactly the same that last year worked ok.

I have reproduced the problem in a MWE.

- Removing the title page makes the text of the first column appear
- Putting the text of the column as items (itemize environment) also makes the text appear
- Removing Madrid theme also makes the text visible

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\title{Beamer columns problem}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}{Columns problem}
\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

Column 1 text does not appear unless in itemize environment 
or removing titlepage

\column{0.4\textwidth}

Column 2

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Columns ok}
\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}

Column 1

\column{0.4\textwidth}

Column 2

\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

What is more strange, diffpdf did not mark any difference for the lost text.

Any idea what is happening?

I am using (extract from the pdflatex log):

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.12.6)  23 FEB 2018 15:18
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**beamer-columns-test.tex
(./beamer-columns-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 6 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2017/01/22 v3.40 A class for typesetting presentations
```

\listfiles output from log:

> *File List*   beamer.cls    2017/01/22 v3.40 A class for typesetting
>   presentations etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX
>   (JAW) beamerbasemodes.sty     beamerbasedecode.sty        ifpdf.sty
>   2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch beamerbaseoptions.sty
>   keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC) geometry.sty
>   2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry   ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect
>   VTeX and its facilities (HO)  ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides
>   ifxetex conditional   size11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX
>   file (size option)  pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision
>   1.7) graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR) graphics.sty    2016/10/09 v1.0u Standard LaTeX Graphics
>   (DPC,SPQR)
>       trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC) graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration   pdftex.def
>   2017/01/12 v0.06k Graphics/color for pdfTeX infwarerr.sty
>   2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO) 
>   ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use
>   (HO)   pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
>   pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31) everyshi.sty
>   2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)   pgfrcs.code.tex
>   pgfsys.code.tex pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision
>   1.9) pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)   xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
>   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration 
>   pgfcore.code.tex  xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1 atbegshi.sty
>   2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO) hyperref.sty    2016/06/24
>   v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16
>   v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO) hobsub-generic.sty
>   2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)   hobsub.sty
>   2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO) ifluatex.sty
>   2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)  intcalc.sty
>   2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
>   etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands
>   (HO) kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
>   kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO) pdftexcmds.sty
>   2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
>   pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features
>   (HO) bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big
>   integers (HO)   bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector
>   datatype (HO) uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited
>   unique counter (HO) letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment
>   for LaTeX macros (HO)  hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for
>   package hooks (HO) xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
>   atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document
>   (HO) refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label
>   references (HO)  hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for
>   hyperref/bookmark (HO)  auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for
>   auxiliary files (HO) kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value
>   format for package options (HO)   pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q
>   Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO) hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06
>   v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
>        url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.  hpdftex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for pdfTeX
>   rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files
>   (HO) beamerbaserequires.sty     beamerbasecompatibility.sty
>   beamerbasefont.sty      amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font
>   symbols amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
>   beamerbasetranslator.sty     translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
>   translator-language-mappings.tex beamerbasemisc.sty
>   beamerbasetwoscreens.sty     beamerbaseoverlay.sty
>   beamerbasetitle.sty     beamerbasesection.sty     beamerbaseframe.sty 
>   beamerbaseverbatim.sty     beamerbaseframesize.sty
>   beamerbaseframecomponents.sty     beamerbasecolor.sty
>   beamerbasenotes.sty     beamerbasetoc.sty     beamerbasetemplates.sty 
>   beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty     beamerbaseboxes.sty
>   beamerbaselocalstructure.sty     enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00
>   enumerate extensions (DPC) beamerbasenavigation.sty
>   beamerbasetheorems.sty      amsmath.sty    2016/11/05 v2.16a AMS math
>   features  amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text   amsgen.sty
>   1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions   amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d
>   Bold Symbols   amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
>   amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2 beamerbasethemes.sty
>   beamerthemedefault.sty     beamerfontthemedefault.sty
>   beamercolorthemedefault.sty     beamerinnerthemedefault.sty
>   beamerouterthemedefault.sty     beamerthemeMadrid.sty
>   beamercolorthemewhale.sty     beamercolorthemeorchid.sty
>   beamerinnerthemerounded.sty     beamerouterthemeinfolines.sty
>   supp-pdf.mkii epstopdf-base.sty    2016/05/15 v2.6 Base part for
>   package epstopdf   grfext.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Manage graphics
>   extensions (HO) epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of
>   (r)epstopdf for TeX Live  nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44
>   Cross-referencing by name of section gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16
>   v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO) beamer-columns-test.out
>   beamer-columns-test.out translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict
>   translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict
>   translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict
>   translator-months-dictionary-English.dict
>   translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict
>   translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict
>       umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
>       umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B  ***********
>
> Package atveryend Info: Executing hook `AtEndAfterFileList' on input
>   line 41. Package rerunfilecheck Info: File`beamer-columns-test.out'
>   has not changed. (rerunfilecheck)             Checksum:
>   D41D8CD98F00B204E9800998ECF8427E;0.
>
> LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences (Font)
>   up to 1.0pt have occurred.
>
> )  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  16852 strings out of
>   494883  321780 string characters out of 6179094  388889 words of
>   memory out of 5000000  19761 multiletter control sequences out of
>   15000+600000  10258 words of font info for 38 fonts, out of 8000000
>   for 9000  40 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191  48i,16n,51p,785b,557s
>   stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
>    Output
>   written on beamer-columns-test.pdf (3 pages, 36095 bytes). PDF
>   statistics:  117 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)  98 compressed
>   objects within 1 object stream  7 named destinations out of 1000 (max.
>   500000)  61 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max.
>   10000000)

Complete log in pastebin: https://pastebin.com/4Kvm2Ezg

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour on my machine. Which version of `beamer` does run on your installation?

Comment: me either can't reproduce your problem. tested with recent beamer (3.50)

Comment: I am editing the question to add version info. From the log: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2017.12.6)  23 FEB 2018 15:18
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**beamer-columns-test.tex
(./beamer-columns-test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017/01/01> patch level 3
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 6 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamer.cls
Document Class: beamer 2017/01/22 v3.40 A class for typesetting presentations

Comment: Can you please show the complete .log file?

Comment: And perhaps include a `\listfiles` in your file?

Comment: Trying to add the complete log file, but exceeds the maximum number of characters for the question. Any suggestion how to attach the file?

Comment: At least show the results of `\listfiles`.

Comment: Added the \listfiles output

Comment: @airos A tip: If you include a `@` sign in front of a username, this user will be notified that you posted a reply.

Comment: @airos To post the log file I suggest https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @Skillmon I've uploaded the log to pastebin.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I have managed to generate the pdf correctly in another computer (with an older system), but I am still curious about this weird effect.

Comment: @airos Try to place https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/master/base/beamerbasecolor.sty in your working folder.

Answer (score 3):

This bug has been fixed in beamer v.3.41

In case you cannot update, place https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/master/base/beamerbasecolor.sty in your working directory

Answer (score 0):

If placing the file in your directory results in error messages (as it does for me),
you can also just write the following line before the text that is not visible:

```
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}\usebeamercolor*{normal text}
```

It will change the font color to black, since the reason that you don't see the text is probably that your heading color is white, and the text of the first column is shown in the heading color.